Cannot load custom fonts in expo via manifest
I've followed the guide at https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/font/#installation to load custom fonts into my expo/react app. Then defined two fonts on the app.json file like this:
"plugins": [
      [
        "expo-font",
        {
          "fonts": [
            "./assets/fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf",
            "./assets/fonts/OpenSans-Bold.ttf"
          ]
        }
      ]
    ]

At this point I tried to use a font directly on a style property with multiple names without success, based on the docs I should be able to use this directly with the same font name as the file name.
Then I started thinking that maybe I still need useFonts but using this method the load is not async, since the fonts have been compiled into the project. So I then added on my App.js:
export default function App() {
  const [userNumber, setUserNumber] = useState();
  const [isGameOver, setIsGameOver] = useState(false);

  useFonts({
    "open-sans": require("./assets/fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf"),
    "open-sans-bold": require("./assets/fonts/OpenSans-Bold.ttf"),
  });

Then on a style property on another file I have:

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  title: {
    fontFamily: "open-sans",
    fontSize: 24,
    color: "white",
    textAlign: "center",
    borderWidth: 2,
    borderColor: "yellow",
    padding: 12,
  },
});

However even after I rebuild the project, delete node_modules folder, all run npx expo start again, I still get:
Logs for your project will appear below. Press Ctrl+C to exit.
› Opening on iOS...
› Opening exp://192.168.3.121:8081 on iPhone 15 Plus
› Opening the iOS simulator, this might take a moment.
› Press ? │ show all commands
iOS Bundled 2100ms (node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js)
 WARN  fontFamily "open-sans" is not a system font and has not been loaded through expo-font. 
    at RCTText
    at Text (http://192.168.3.121:8081/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle//&platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&transform.engine=hermes&transform.bytecode=true&transform.routerRoot=app:88806:27)
    at Title (http://192.168.3.121:8081/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle//&platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&transform.engine=hermes&transform.bytecode=true&transform.routerRoot=app:136101:24)
    at RCTView
    at View (http://192.168.3.121:8081/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle//&platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&transform.engine=hermes&transform.bytecode=true&transform.routerRoot=app:70183:43)
    at StartGameScreen (http://192.168.3.121:8081/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle//&platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&transform.engine=hermes&transform.bytecode=true&transform.routerRoot=app:135876:28)
    at RCTSafeAreaView
    at RCTView
    at View (http://192.168.3.121:8081/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle//&platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&transform.engine=hermes&transform.bytecode=true&transform.routerRoot=app:70183:43)
    at ImageBackground (http://192.168.3.121:8081/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle//&platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&transform.engine=hermes&transform.bytecode=true&transform.routerRoot=app:126932:36)
    at ViewManagerAdapter_ExpoLinearGradient
    at ExpoLinearGradient (http://192.168.3.121:8081/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle//&platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&transform.engine=hermes&transform.bytecode=true&transform.routerRoot=app:132266:38)
    at LinearGradient (http://192.168.3.121:8081/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle//&platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&transform.engine=hermes&transform.bytecode=true&transform.routerRoot=app:136236:36)
    at App (http://192.168.3.121:8081/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle//&platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&transform.engine=hermes&transform.bytecode=true&transform.routerRoot=app:135772:41)
    at withDevTools(App) (http://192.168.3.121:8081/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle//&platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&transform.engine=hermes&transform.bytecode=true&transform.routerRoot=app:135341:27)
    at RCTView
    at View (http://192.168.3.121:8081/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle//&platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&transform.engine=hermes&transform.bytecode=true&transform.routerRoot=app:70183:43)
    at RCTView
    at View (http://192.168.3.121:8081/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle//&platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&transform.engine=hermes&transform.bytecode=true&transform.routerRoot=app:70183:43)
    at AppContainer (http://192.168.3.121:8081/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle//&platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&transform.engine=hermes&transform.bytecode=true&transform.routerRoot=app:69994:36)
    at main(RootComponent) (http://192.168.3.121:8081/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle//&platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&transform.engine=hermes&transform.bytecode=true&transform.routerRoot=app:117467:28)

My package.json for reference:
{
  "name": "guess-game",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "~50.0.14",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "~12.7.2",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.11.1",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.73.6",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.26.4",
    "expo-font": "~11.10.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0"
  },
  "private": true
}


Wondering now if there's a subtancial difference in compiled elements in running npx expo start vs npm expo run ios. Could the fonts not be included in the former?
